# How to show LINQ data in view in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I am using a action called **scrap** as

```
public ActionResult Scrap()
 {
    var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
    var document = webGet.Load(Url);
    var wikians = from info in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='results']")
                  from link in info.SelectNodes("p//a").Where(x => x.Attributes.Contains("href"))
                  from content in info.SelectNodes("p").Where(y => y.HasAttributes != true)
                  select new
                    {
                      LinkURL = link.Attributes["href"].Value,
                      Text = content.InnerText                             
                    };

 return View();
}
```

Now I want to show all LinkURL and Text in view. For that I tried to use a model called **WikiModel** as

```
public class WikiModel
{
  public string url { get; set; }
  public string content { get; set; }
}
```

Now how can I go further so that I can show all infomation in my view. We can do so using the `wikimodel` but how to add all `scrap` action's data in this `wikimodel`? I don't know how to manipulate his `select new` of `LINQ` to save data in model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, you need to return list of your `WikiModel` objects from your query:

```
 var wikians = from info in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='results']")
                  from link in info.SelectNodes("p//a").Where(x => x.Attributes.Contains("href"))
                  from content in info.SelectNodes("p").Where(y => y.HasAttributes != true)
                  select new WikiModel
                    {
                      url = link.Attributes["href"].Value,
                      content = content.InnerText                             
                    };
```

You can pass this through to the view as the `Model`:

```
return View(wikians);
```

In your view, you now have access to this list via the `Model`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Scrap()
 {
    var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
    var document = webGet.Load(Url);
    var wikians = from info in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='results']")
                  from link in info.SelectNodes("p//a").Where(x => x.Attributes.Contains("href"))
                  from content in info.SelectNodes("p").Where(y => y.HasAttributes != true)
                  select new WikiModel

                    {
                      LinkURL = link.Attributes["href"].Value,
                      Text = content.InnerText                             
                    };

 return View(wikians);
}
```

Comment: Why are you casting to `List<WikiModel>`?

Comment: yeah creating problem related to casting